# Syntax error on small code for ageing work

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
lst = []
num = int(input('How many people?: '))
for n in range(num):
 age = float(input('Input Age: ')
  seconds = str(age*31536000)

print("You lived: ", seconds)
lst.append(age)

print("Highest age: ", max(lst), "\n Least aged: ", min(lst))
```

I don't know why this doesnt work, any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your error message.

Comment: Your indentation seems off, which may just be a copy paste issue, but could be the cause of your error. If you can edit your question to include the error message, we may be able to help you further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close the parenthesis on line 4. `lst.append` and the print statement before it should probably be in the loop (Credit: Luke Nelson). Here's the fixed code:

```
lst = []
num = int(input('How many people?: '))
for n in range(num):
 age = float(input('Input Age: '))
 seconds = str(age*31536000)
 print("You lived: ", seconds)
 lst.append(age)

print("Highest age: ", max(lst), "\n Least aged: ", min(lst))
```

Comment: Although this fixes the syntax error, I'm not entirely sure it's "right"...  The first print statement and lst.append should probably be in the loop. It might be good to add this to your answer to help out OP.

Comment: @LukeNelson Ok I will change the code.